# spring: How to define property file location priority?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

We need to attain the following behavior to resolve the property file (say abc.properties) in my spring project:
1. Try to find abc.properties adjacent to my jar file
2. If the file abc.properties is not found beside the jar file, search it in a folder named configs.

How can We achieve the above using spring propertyplaceholderconfigurer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For XML based configuration

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:abc.properties</value>
            <value>file:/some/folder/path/override.properites</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

> You can also use `context` namespace:

```
<context:property-placeholder locations="classpath:abc.properties,file:/some/folder/path/override.properites"/>
```

> For annotation based configuration, you can add following annotation to any of your `@Configuration` files

```
@PropertySource({
    "classpath:abc.properties",
    "file:/some/folder/path/override.properites" //This will override values with same keys as in abc.properties
})
```

> For more details:
>   http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Answer (score 1):

The key is to set `ignoreResourceNotFound` property to `true`.

Example using `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`:

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:abc.properties</value>
            <value>file:/path-to-file/abc.properites</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Example using `@PropertySource`:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:abc.properties", "file:/path-to-file/abc.properties" }, ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
class MyConfig {
    ...
}
```